# Best Json library for Windows phone 7 App development

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

I am new to win 7 app dev. I have done app dev in android and have used org.json native libs.
Example : `org.json.JSONArray` , `org.json.JSONException` , `org.json.JSONObject`

I want similar functionalities in C# what i had in java with this json lib. Please tell me best lib to do that.
Currently i am using codetitans library. Code :

```
JSonWriter wr = new JSonWriter(); 
wr.WriteObjectBegin();
wr.WriteMember("set_cookie","0");
wr.WriteMember("test",writer.ToString());
wr.WriteObjectEnd();
string line = wr.ToString();
/* This creates a jsonwriter object and then write key, value pairs.*/
```

Comment: Do you have something against the `DataContractJsonSerializer` in the framework?

Comment: @RowlandShaw json.net has been repeatedly shown to be faster than DataContractJsonSerializer in most cases. It's also easier to debug issues and deosn't require as much work to integrate. In ASP.NET MVC 4 Microsoft even recommend json.net over DCJS.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend trying JSON.NET :-

http://json.codeplex.com/

The following provides an example as to how you might serialise and deseralise using JSON.NET :-

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Comment: I would recommend this too, but maybe you should elaborate a bit more in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to consider [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text).Text as this has recently been shown to be the fastest JSON serialiser available.